# Liberar botao salvar com permissao

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho um tabela de cadastro num modal, ele tem o botao de salvar e cancelar,
somente ao preencher todos os input e select obrigatorio ele libera o salvar, e salva no banco de dados, ta tudo funcionando, só que se eu ir no alterar ele traz todas as opções selecionada conforme foi salvo, só nao vem o botao de salvar liberado só libera se passar o focus em todos os campos obrigatório. Eu gostaria que ele liberasse automatico já que todos os campos obrigatórios estao salvos.

esse é o javascript

```
jQuery(function() {
                    var $inputs = $(".inpSenha"), $button = $(".btnSalvar1");

                    var limpos = 0;

                    // verificação inicial
                    $inputs.each(function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var val = $this.val();
                        val || limpos++;
                        $this.data("val-antigo", val);
                    });

                    $button.prop("disabled", !!limpos);

                    $inputs.on("change keyup mouseup", function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var val = $this.val();
                        limpos += (val ? 0 : 1)
                                - ($this.data("val-antigo") ? 0 : 1);
                        $this.data("val-antigo", val);
                        $button.prop("disabled", !!limpos);
                    });

                });
```

esse é o Html do botão salvar

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnSalvar1" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="salvarPessoas()">Salvar</button>
```

e o inpSenha e a classe que vai no input ou select que sera obrigatório
que poder me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você — provavelmente — está utilizando o Bootstrap, então, ao abrir o modal, você pode utilizar a função de *callback* `show.bs.modal`. Toda vez que você abrir o modal, o *Bootstrap* irá invocar essa função.

**Exemplo:**

```
const modal = $('#exampleModal');

modal.on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  /* Realiza a verificação se todos os campos estão preenchidos */
})
```

**Segue exemplo:**
<sup>Apenas os campos "Name" e "Terms" estão como obrigatórios</sup>

```js
const modal = $('#exampleModal');

modal.on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  checkInputs();
})

modal.on("change keyup mouseup", ".inpSenha", () => {
  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  $(".inpSenha").each((index, el) => {
    if (el.value == "") {
      $(modal).find("#save").prop("disabled", true);
      return false;
    } else {
      $(modal).find("#save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Open</button>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="inpSenha" id="name" /><br>

        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="username" />
        <Br>
        
        <label for="terms">Terms</label>
        <select id="terms" class="inpSenha">
          <option value="" selected>Select</option>
          <option value="1">Agree</option>
          <option value="0">Disagree</option>
        </select>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="save">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie um *event click* para o botão <kbd>Alterar</kbd> para liberar o botão <kbd>Salvar</kbd>:

```
$("id ou classe do botão Alterar").click(function(){
    $(".btnSalvar1").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Quando fechar a modal, desabilite novamente o botão:

```
$('id da modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $(".btnSalvar1").prop("disabled", true);
});
```